# PHP - ftp_put failed to open stream?

Tags: php, ftp

I have a website on a remote host.
I am trying to get the php page to upload a file to another remote server through ftp.

The server I am trying to upload to has these directories(all have permission 777):

```
/
/public_html
/public_html/files
```

lets say for example these were the ftp details:

```
host: example.com
user: user
pass: pass
port: 21
```

can anyone please help me understand why this code isn't working:

```
$file = 'C:\Users\[my username]\Desktop\somefile.txt';
$remote_file = '/public_html/files/file.txt';

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect("example.com",21);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, "user", "pass");
echo $login_result;
// upload a file
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
    echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

when I run it I get the following message:

```
Warning: ftp_put(C:\Users\User\Desktop\somefile.txt) [function.ftp-put]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/public_html/page.php on line 11
```

Any help is really appreciated ive researched like crazy and have been trying for ages.

Comment: What happens when you change to the '/public_html/files' directory using ftp_chdir() and use $remote_file='file.txt'. Does it let you change the directory? My interpretation of your error message is that the directory '/home/user/public_html/files/' does not exist on the server you are uploading the file to.

Comment: See the comment left by "Kev" in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php), it also may be worth looking into.

Comment: i did what you said and changing to '/public_html/files' worked without errors. although uploading still failed with the same error message, my guess (and presumably yours) is that it must be the local file that doesn't exist, but it does :/ ??

Comment: i added this code to test if the file exists:
if (file_exists($file)){
  echo "file exists";
 }else{
  echo "file not found";
 }
it returns false no matter the file path (even if it exists), am i declaring the path wrong?

Comment: I can confirm that the code in your last comment does work for me. If the file does exist and it is not showing, maybe there is a problem with permissions? Perhaps try changing permissions of your file to 0666 and see if the file exists?

Comment: sorry i just realized what i was trying to do. i was trying to move a file from the client side to the server side, which according to my research isn't possible. you helped me alot though thank you, if you give the answer "you can not move file from client to server", or along those lines i will happily give you the rep.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but you should instead post and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

$remote_file = 'files/file.txt';
You should try this