# HTTP file upload works for 1 file, but no other files

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm working on a website which uses a database to get product-images.
Everything works just fine, so I wanted to make a page to easily transfer image-files from my local desktop to my ftp.server. Now this really weird thing happens and I cant figure out why.

While in testing phase, I kept on trying with one specific file "haircut.jpg". Just a random pic a downloaded. After a while, the page worked and I could upload that file "haircut.jpg" to my ftp-server.

Now I want to start using the page to upload more images to my ftp-server, but ONLY that image "haircut.jpg" will work. Every other image I try fails, and it gives me the next error:

> Warning: ftp_put(kabouter.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in...

I really have no clue what this could be. I deleted the "haircut.jpg" file from my ftp-server, but I can keep uploading it again and again, it always works. I tried with another browser; same problem continues.

The other files are in the EXACT same folder, about the same size (I tried smaller and larger). I tried other files with .jpg. I tried other folders. Not workings, just that one particular "haircut.jpg" works.

All code I use for the ftp-transfer is as follows:

```
//FTP:
$ftp_server = "ftpserver";
$ftp_username = "username";
$ftp_userpass = "password";
$remote_dir = "/test/";

$target_file = $remote_dir.basename($_FILES['afbeelding']["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

//Setup basic connection
//ftp_connect(host, port [def=21], timeout [def=90])
$ftpConn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftpConn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);
```

I think the next block of code is not causing the problem, but I'll post it anyway:

```
//Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES['afbeelding']["name"]);
    if($check !== false){
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    }
    else{
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
//Check if file already exists
if(in_array(basename($_FILES['afbeelding']["name"]), ftp_nlist($ftpConn, $remote_dir)))
{
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

//Check file size
if($_FILES['afbeelding']["size"] > 3000000)
{
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

//Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif")
{
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

This is were the FTP-transfer actually takes place:

```
//Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if($uploadOk == 0){
    echo "<br>Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
}

//If everything is OK, try to upload the file
else
{
    //Check if ftp transfer was succesfull
    if(ftp_put($ftpConn, $target_file, basename($_FILES['afbeelding']["name"]), FTP_ASCII )){
        echo "The file ". basename($_FILES['afbeelding']["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    }
    else {
        "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}

//Remember to always close the ftp connection
ftp_close($ftpConn);
```

I hope anyone recognizes the problem and is able to help me out. I'm clueless right now.

Comment: You probably read this already  http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp_put.php  but it seems to suggest that `FTP_BINARY` is needed where you have `FTP_ASCII`  Perhaps the file which works has somehow got converted/corrupted to an ASCII file by an earlier upload process so will upload.  It could be that `$targetfile`  is blank for some reason - try echoing it before the `ftp_put`   `ftp_pasv ()` might also be worth exploring, on the same page.

Comment: There is an "`echo`" missing before the"Sorry, there was an error..." which could cause a problem.

Comment: This suggests that you can't upload using PHP FTP from a local machine to a remote server location - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709893/php-ftp-put-failed-to-open-stream?rq=1 - perhaps you need to consider a file upload script like this one http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp using a file type of input to select and upload it. Possibly the one that works is lurking in a temp folder somewhere by sheer luck, and so can be copied across on the server.

Comment: Steve, thanks for the reply. As a matter of fact, I did try changing to FTP_BINARY, but that didn't work out for me. I did not try the "ftp_pasv() yet, so I will give that a try later this day. About the w3schools example; thats exactly the script I'm using. I now see I did not mention that I'm using input=file, but I do. The value of that field is "afbeelding", which is mentioned multiple times in the code I provided as; "basename($_FILES['afbeelding']["name"])".
I'll be coming back to this later when I tried some of your offered ideas, thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to thank you too for your input. As my specific (first) problem was solved by Martin Prikryl in the other comment, my next problem was that my transfered file got corrupted. Changing FTP_ASCII to FTP_BINARY did the trick! Now all works fine :) thanks!

Comment: Well done - file uploading is a bit confusing until you get the hang of it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"name"` element of the `$_FILES` array does not contain name of a file you can read! It's a name of the file as on the user's client machine, not on the server.

The filename of the file, where the uploaded file was temporarily stored to on the server, is in `"tmp_name"` element.

You must have some forgotten copy of the `"haircut.jpg"` in the folder where your PHP file is.

Just replace all instances of the `"name"` used to access the file with `"tmp_name"` (random name). Keep the (pretty) `"name"`, where you deal with FTP path.

For the structure of the `$_FILES`, see [POST method uploads](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

Comment: First of all, thanks! You were right about the fact that i had a forgotten copy of the "haircut.jpg" in the folder where my PHP file is.

But, now it appears to be that "ftp_put($ftpConn, $target_file, basename($_FILES['afbeelding']['tmp_name'])" checks if there is a file with "tmp_name" in the folder where my php file is. I know you already suggested a solution, but I think I'm to less experienced to get it working. I've tried to change the 'name' to 'tmp_name' were I think it should, but I still don't get it to work. Perhaps there is something else I should use rather than "ftp_put()"?

Comment: Because you strip the path information from the `$_FILES['afbeelding']['tmp_name']` by the [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) call. Remove it, use just `ftp_put($ftpConn, $target_file, $_FILES['afbeelding']['tmp_name'])`.

Comment: This really solved everything! Not only does it solve my problem, now I have a better understanding of $_FILES and basename too, your help is greatly appreciated. I would upvote this answer if I could, but since I'm pretty new to stackoverflow, I can't, sorry for that. But again, thanks a lot!