# failed to open stream: No such file or directory issue

Tags: php, laravel, ftp

Sorry i do not know much english

I need upload image file in other VPS.

My framework is Laravel 5.2.

after submit show this error:

`ftp_put(/tmp/phpzGLEyw): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

This code:

```
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);
foreach($file as $files){
            $filename = $files->getClientOriginalName();
            $extension = $files->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $picture = sha1($filename . time()) . '.' . $extension;
            $folder = Auth::guard('vendor')->user()->id;

            $url = '/public_html/';                

            if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, $url . $picture, $files, FTP_ASCII))
            {
                $m = "Successfully uploaded.";
            }
            else
            {
                $m = "Error uploading.";
            }
}

ftp_close($ftp_conn);
```

For example:

print_r($files):

```
Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile Object ( [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => Screenshot from 2017-03-23 13-41-47.png [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => image/png [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 6194 [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0 [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /tmp/phpLqy7Bt [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => phpLqy7Bt )
```

Where is problem?

Comment: Check if directory exists and check the permissions.

Comment: @Cuchu Hi, I can move in localhost but i can not move file in other host.

Comment: Your connection to remote host it's ok? in the php ftp_put documentation, $files(local_file) is a route to local file, but in your example is a object.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php#refsect1-function.ftp-put-examples
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709893/php-ftp-put-failed-to-open-stream

Comment: @Cuchu Connection is true, I update my question.

Comment: Ok.. $file is a object UploadedFile, no local resource.. try to connect remote host and confirm that url path exists and correct permissions to write. And change $files in ftp_put to $files->path() (https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.html#method_path)

Comment: check if /tmp/phpzGLEyw(files in the file array) exists in local host maybe you delete files :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. $file is a object UploadedFile, no local resource.. try to connect remote host and confirm that url path exists and correct permissions to write. And change $files in ftp_put to $files->path()

Check if /tmp/phpzGLEyw(files in the file array) exists in local host maybe you delete files :p

Nice Ali!